# How to have a child that expands to all (vertical) space of the parent and THEN have vertical scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to have a component that expands to all (vertical) space in parent and when left without space scrolls it's content (vertically)?

Example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body{
            background-color: azure;            
        }

        #parent{
            background-color: lightcoral;
        }  
        #child{
            background-color: green;            
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id='parent'>
  This parent should fill all the space until the end of view port
  <div id='child'>
    This child should 'trigger' a scrolling once it fills the available space (from parent).

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas suscipit velit et sodales vehicula. Ut nec eleifend orci. Duis commodo hendrerit lorem quis tempus. Nullam scelerisque sed justo quis fringilla. Aenean odio ligula, lobortis porttitor finibus nec, consequat vel massa. Sed odio augue, efficitur vitae tortor at, egestas fermentum est. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Phasellus placerat varius vestibulum. Suspendisse posuere ultricies interdum. Nullam dapibus ut velit a placerat. Nunc ullamcorper sit amet urna eget molestie. Maecenas ullamcorper dui ut elit tristique, sit amet rutrum ante maximus. Curabitur posuere, est quis rhoncus facilisis, enim ex semper eros, eu pulvinar sapien massa egestas quam. Aenean dictum dolor eget arcu tincidunt rutrum.
    In eu euismod lacus. Sed efficitur quam ac enim tincidunt, eget tempus libero finibus. Nulla varius varius pulvinar. Etiam urna dolor, vulputate eget lobortis et, ornare nec lacus. Pellentesque nec bibendum tellus, id interdum urna. Praesent cursus vitae ligula nec vulputate. Vivamus nec ex nec ex bibendum placerat interdum sit amet ipsum. Nulla vel ultrices erat, vel fringilla dolor. Proin auctor turpis nec dui tincidunt interdum. 
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas suscipit velit et sodales vehicula. Ut nec eleifend orci. Duis commodo hendrerit lorem quis tempus. Nullam scelerisque sed justo quis fringilla. Aenean odio ligula, lobortis porttitor finibus nec, consequat vel massa. Sed odio augue, efficitur vitae tortor at, egestas fermentum est. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Phasellus placerat varius vestibulum. Suspendisse posuere ultricies interdum. Nullam dapibus ut velit a placerat. Nunc ullamcorper sit amet urna eget molestie. Maecenas ullamcorper dui ut elit tristique, sit amet rutrum ante maximus. Curabitur posuere, est quis rhoncus facilisis, enim ex semper eros, eu pulvinar sapien massa egestas quam. Aenean dictum dolor eget arcu tincidunt rutrum.
    In eu euismod lacus. Sed efficitur quam ac enim tincidunt, eget tempus libero finibus. Nulla varius varius pulvinar. Etiam urna dolor, vulputate eget lobortis et, ornare nec lacus. Pellentesque nec bibendum tellus, id interdum urna. Praesent cursus vitae ligula nec vulputate. Vivamus nec ex nec ex bibendum placerat interdum sit amet ipsum. Nulla vel ultrices erat, vel fringilla dolor. Proin auctor turpis nec dui tincidunt interdum. 
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas suscipit velit et sodales vehicula. Ut nec eleifend orci. Duis commodo hendrerit lorem quis tempus. Nullam scelerisque sed justo quis fringilla. Aenean odio ligula, lobortis porttitor finibus nec, consequat vel massa. Sed odio augue, efficitur vitae tortor at, egestas fermentum est. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Phasellus placerat varius vestibulum. Suspendisse posuere ultricies interdum. Nullam dapibus ut velit a placerat. Nunc ullamcorper sit amet urna eget molestie. Maecenas ullamcorper dui ut elit tristique, sit amet rutrum ante maximus. Curabitur posuere, est quis rhoncus facilisis, enim ex semper eros, eu pulvinar sapien massa egestas quam. Aenean dictum dolor eget arcu tincidunt rutrum.
    In eu euismod lacus. Sed efficitur quam ac enim tincidunt, eget tempus libero finibus. Nulla varius varius pulvinar. Etiam urna dolor, vulputate eget lobortis et, ornare nec lacus. Pellentesque nec bibendum tellus, id interdum urna. Praesent cursus vitae ligula nec vulputate. Vivamus nec ex nec ex bibendum placerat interdum sit amet ipsum. Nulla vel ultrices erat, vel fringilla dolor. Proin auctor turpis nec dui tincidunt interdum. 
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas suscipit velit et sodales vehicula. Ut nec eleifend orci. Duis commodo hendrerit lorem quis tempus. Nullam scelerisque sed justo quis fringilla. Aenean odio ligula, lobortis porttitor finibus nec, consequat vel massa. Sed odio augue, efficitur vitae tortor at, egestas fermentum est. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Phasellus placerat varius vestibulum. Suspendisse posuere ultricies interdum. Nullam dapibus ut velit a placerat. Nunc ullamcorper sit amet urna eget molestie. Maecenas ullamcorper dui ut elit tristique, sit amet rutrum ante maximus. Curabitur posuere, est quis rhoncus facilisis, enim ex semper eros, eu pulvinar sapien massa egestas quam. Aenean dictum dolor eget arcu tincidunt rutrum.
    In eu euismod lacus. Sed efficitur quam ac enim tincidunt, eget tempus libero finibus. Nulla varius varius pulvinar. Etiam urna dolor, vulputate eget lobortis et, ornare nec lacus. Pellentesque nec bibendum tellus, id interdum urna. Praesent cursus vitae ligula nec vulputate. Vivamus nec ex nec ex bibendum placerat interdum sit amet ipsum. Nulla vel ultrices erat, vel fringilla dolor. Proin auctor turpis nec dui tincidunt interdum. 
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas suscipit velit et sodales vehicula. Ut nec eleifend orci. Duis commodo hendrerit lorem quis tempus. Nullam scelerisque sed justo quis fringilla. Aenean odio ligula, lobortis porttitor finibus nec, consequat vel massa. Sed odio augue, efficitur vitae tortor at, egestas fermentum est. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Phasellus placerat varius vestibulum. Suspendisse posuere ultricies interdum. Nullam dapibus ut velit a placerat. Nunc ullamcorper sit amet urna eget molestie. Maecenas ullamcorper dui ut elit tristique, sit amet rutrum ante maximus. Curabitur posuere, est quis rhoncus facilisis, enim ex semper eros, eu pulvinar sapien massa egestas quam. Aenean dictum dolor eget arcu tincidunt rutrum.
    In eu euismod lacus. Sed efficitur quam ac enim tincidunt, eget tempus libero finibus. Nulla varius varius pulvinar. Etiam urna dolor, vulputate eget lobortis et, ornare nec lacus. Pellentesque nec bibendum tellus, id interdum urna. Praesent cursus vitae ligula nec vulputate. Vivamus nec ex nec ex bibendum placerat interdum sit amet ipsum. Nulla vel ultrices erat, vel fringilla dolor. Proin auctor turpis nec dui tincidunt interdum.     
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I would prefer a pure CSS solution than a mixed of CSS and JavaScript.

Comment: Hi! Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/). Show the context of the parent, anything else that may be in it, the CSS that applies to the parent, etc. Fundamentally, though: Making the parent a [`flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Flex) container with `flex-direction: column` and applying `flex: 1` and `overflow: auto` to the child should work, depending on the unknowns mentioned.

Comment: You could add 'display: flex; flex-direction: column;' on the parent and then 'flex: 1;  overflow-y: auto;' on the child.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Done. I hope it's clearer now

Answer (score 1):

Certainly possible with `flexbox` BUT the parent needs to have a limited height (either manually or some other constraint) otherwise the child won't know when overflow will occur and thus scroll apply.

Applying a fixed `height` or `max-height` to the parent and then make the parent a flex-column.

The child is then given `flex:1` so it expands to the maximum of the parent and `overflow: auto` to scroll when the parent's maximum is reached.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  max-height: 50vh;
  background: blue;
  width:70vw;
  padding: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.child {
  flex:1;
  overflow:auto;
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore explicabo sit nobis non tenetur repudiandae! Possimus obcaecati nesciunt cum et inventore ducimus perspiciatis similique sit fugit esse nulla corporis quo, dolore ipsa? Dolor hic nemo labore</div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero nulla, reiciendis ipsum nam suscipit earum fugiat aliquam, deserunt assumenda obcaecati, quod nostrum voluptates. Vero est error voluptas fugit consectetur quaerat quisquam nesciunt! Similique fugiat, voluptatibus, accusantium hic illo blanditiis illum eum porro consequuntur cum commodi! Necessitatibus, voluptatem? Voluptatem aperiam architecto aspernatur omnis dicta repellat, at ut dolor minus quidem exercitationem alias atque quaerat, adipisci neque maiores tempore quas repellendus eveniet temporibus. Et nihil iste harum quaerat adipisci accusantium sapiente temporibus ratione non. Molestiae veritatis a dolorem natus. Eveniet labore hic, repellendus amet, laudantium nihil repudiandae, tempora enim laborum consequatur facilis? Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo ea eos quam dolor qui, incidunt vel ab, quaerat vero quibusdam quis alias voluptas! Quas, dolores!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You kinda nailed but is there any way to do it without specifying the parent's height? I want the parent to flow/expand up to the bottom of the viewport but the child to trigger scroll if no space for it....

Comment: Nope, overflow/scroll will not occur unless it knows *when* to do so. The parent might expand to the size of a further grandparent (or whatever) but you'd need to provide more detail in a separate question.